# Can't POST to /me/feed in Batched Requests

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm having a hard time "POSTING" to /me/feed in batch requests.

Sending Batched GET requests works fine, but as soon as I switch the METHOD value to "POST", I get an "Invalid Parameter" error (100, sub code: 1349125). The only params in the batch requests are method, access_token, relative_url and message.

Comment: i don´t think batch request are built for those things. several /me/feed postings would surely be spam anyway, and you are not allowed to prefill the message parameter, for example.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending all the parameters correctly?

Comment: As far as I know I am sending them correctly. I can batch most other requests in the same format. I'm including access_tokens for each request. As stated before, I can successfully make the GET requests, just not POST.

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't an issue with the API. @Igy was right and I was simply malforming on params being sent. Since the GET requests ignored these params, it seemed like it only worked on a GET.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time.